# Simple form array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form that updates an `@identity` object. Two `@identity` attributes need to be assigned from a separate collection `@accounts`.

```
@accounts = [{
   'name' => 'A',
   'page_id' => 1},
  {
   'name' => 'B',
   'page_id' => 2
  }]
```

The form needs display the `name`, but pass both the `name` and `page_id`.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@identity, :remote => true) do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :page_name, :collection => @accounts.map { |a| a['name'] }, :as => :radio_buttons, :item_wrapper_tag => :li %>

  <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

How can I also pass the matching `page_id` attribute without displaying it?

Comment: You can't mix-and-match strings and symbols. You're setting `a[:name]` but reading `a['name']` which won't work unless this is really a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, and nothing you've posted indicates it is.

Comment: Fixed. `@accounts` shouldn't have been using symbols.

Answer (score 0):

```
:collection => @accounts.map { |e| [e['name'], e['page_id']] }
```

Comment: How do I retrieve these attributes in the controller? Nothing is assigned to `:page_name`

Comment: Not working. Do I need to change `f.input` to something else to pass the attributes as parameters?